# Where should I perform maintenance in my MonoTouch app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS app written in MonoTouch - with each new version, new features are added and I need to add additional fields to the database or perform data maintenance tasks (sometimes these could take a minute or so to run). In many cases, the data/schema will need to be updated before we can allow the user into the application - Is there a standardised way or place in Obj-C or Monotouch to perform these maintenance tasks on startup? Ideally I would want to display a loading display to the user to let them know this is a one time only thing.

My thoughts so far:

- Placing them in FinishedLaunching within the AppDelegate, but it seems like the wrong spot.
- Changing the home view to a view which only upgrades their database and then pushes them on to the next view, but this seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changing the home view to a view which only upgrades their database and then pushes them on to the next view, but this seems like overkill.

That's how I do it ([here is an example](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/iqpurchasing/id575799458?mt=8)) in a few of my apps.

What I do is check in the AppDelegate `FinishedLoading` if this version needs the schema updating, and if it does I make the `window.RootViewController` a DialogViewController which uses the `Default.png` as the background, and then do my updates from there.

This gives the illusion that a progress bar has shown over the top of your splash screen.

For a loading screen you can use [ATM Hud](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/ATMHud) to display a progress bar to the end user.

[image]

Comment: This is the approach I ended up taking.

Answer (score 1):

Finished Launching is definitely the wrong place for such a long operation (because iOS kills the app if it takes to long).

Your second option seems to me to be the right approach. This way you can tell the user what they are waiting for. You could also use this view to tell the user what is new in the app